# Android mapView setShowsUserLocation?

Tags: android, ios, android-mapview

is there an option on Android to set an mapView option like in iOS?

In iOS you can do [mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES] to show the Userslocation? Or am i wrong?

Regards,

float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `MyLocationOverlay` to the `MapView`, and it will display the user's position with a flashing blue dot, if the user is on the map.